# How to view text files on Launchpad raw?

Tags: launchpad

On GitHub there is a "raw" view for every text file in a hosted repo.

For example to view just the text of [a file](https://github.com/kermit666/dotfiles/blob/master/meta/link), I press on the "raw" button and get it [as only text](https://raw.github.com/kermit666/dotfiles/master/meta/link) (which is useful for easy copy-pasting or running scripts using `wget` without installing `git`/`bzr` on a machine).

How can I achieve this for a file hosted on Launchpad, such as [this one](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~bzr-pqm/bzr/bzr.dev/view/head:/Makefile)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't view raw files directly in the browser; you can however **download** them.

[image]

For your specific example: [download file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~bzr-pqm/bzr/bzr.dev/download/head:/Makefile-20050805140406-d96e3498bb61c5bb/Makefile).

Comment: This download URL contains characters that are unpredictable, e.g.
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~loggerhead-team/loggerhead/trunk-rich/download/head:/__init__.py-20080618010557-l75daamahmjxto53-2/__init__.py
Is there are way to guess the URL without the "/__init__.py-20080618010557-l75daamahmjxto53-2"?