# How do you create a *floating* download link to file in bzr hosted on Launchpad?

Tags: downloads, launchpad, bazaar, github

On GitHub it is possible to create a **floating** download link which always points to the latest copy of a file in a branch. An example would be;

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KiCad/kicad-library/master/template/fp-lib-table.for-pretty
```

This is really useful to use in automated install scripts and for linking to from your website.

Is it possible to create a similar style **floating** link to a bzr file hosted on Launchpad?

---

Having the file downloaded **always be the newest version** in the repo (the floating part) is the part I'm stuck with. I can follow the instructions at [How to view text files on Launchpad raw?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336737/how-to-view-text-files-on-launchpad-raw/336745) to get a link like;

```
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kicad-product-committers/kicad/product/download/head:/libraryreposinstall.-20131202165949-wv7mnbj220s2m4cy-1/library-repos-install.sh
```

This link doesn't work though, as it clearly has version information encoded in the URL.

*Thank you for your help!*

Answer (score 1):

The link you quote is actually the right one.  That isn't version information in the URL; it's a unique identifier for the file across its history.